# PHP regex to check a string

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a PHP regex to check a string is:

- 4 characters long
- the 1st character is A-Z (capitalized alphabet)
- the 2nd to 4th characters are numbers (0-9)

A good example is: `A123`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^[A-Z][0-9]{3}$
```

Explanation:

```
^         # start of string
[A-Z]     # one character, A-Z
[0-9]{3}  # three characters, 0-9
$         # end of string
```

Comment: `\d` can be used as a shortcut for `[0-9]` as well.

Comment: @Amber Yup, I was going for something as easy to understand as possible here though. :)